# Foreign Keys with MySQL.Cluster (NDB)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, database-cluster

Since version 7.3 MySQL Cluster should be capable of foreign key constraints. But here is what happens:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

CREATE TABLE t1 (
id INT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE='InnoDB';

CREATE TABLE t2 (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
t1id INT
) ENGINE='InnoDB';

ALTER TABLE t2
ADD CONSTRAINT t2t1 FOREIGN KEY (t1id) REFERENCES t1 (id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

This is using InnoDB and everything works just fine. Now try it with NDB:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

CREATE TABLE t1 (
id INT PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE='NDB';

CREATE TABLE t2 (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
t1id INT
) ENGINE='NDB';

ALTER TABLE t2
ADD CONSTRAINT t2t1 FOREIGN KEY (t1id) REFERENCES t1 (id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

-- ERROR 150 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

And now the weird part:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

CREATE TABLE t1 (
id INT UNIQUE KEY
) ENGINE='NDB';

CREATE TABLE t2 (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
t1id INT
) ENGINE='NDB';

ALTER TABLE t2
ADD CONSTRAINT t2t1 FOREIGN KEY (t1id) REFERENCES t1 (id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Works just fine.

Is there any rule that says "with the NDB storage engine you cannot reference a primary key column in a foreign key constraint" or "with NDB you have to reference UNIQUE KEYS in foreign key constraints"?

To make things even stranger:

If you replace the definition of t1 by

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
id INT UNIQUE KEY NOT NULL
) ENGINE='NDB';
```

you get the same error.

I'm thinking that `PRIMARY KEY` implies `NOT NULL` and that the problem lies not with the former but with the latter.

Comment: can you drop `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause and check?

Comment: @DoSparKot: That actually works. Do you know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I gathered from MySQL site and Dev blogs:

> An important difference to note with the Foreign Key implementation in
>   InnoDB is that **MySQL Cluster does not support the updating of Primary
>   Keys from within the Data Nodes themselves** - instead the **UPDATE is
>   emulated with a DELETE followed by an INSERT operation**. Therefore an
>   UPDATE operation will return an error if the parent reference is using
>   a Primary Key, unless using CASCADE action, in which case the delete
>   operation will result in the corresponding rows in the child table
>   being deleted. **The Engineering team plans to change this behavior in a
>   subsequent preview release**.

- [Foreign Keys in MySQL Cluster](http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/foreign-keys-in-mysql-cluster/)
- [New MySQL Cluster 7.3 Previews](https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/cluster-7.3-dmr.html)
- [MySQL Cluster 7.3 Labs Release – Foreign Keys Are In!](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/mysql_cluster_7_3_labs)
- [Recent MySQL Cluster posts](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/category/Oracle/MySQL+Cluster)

Support for such operation is not yet confirmed.

Comment: So, because an `UPDATE t1 SET id=2 WHERE id=1` results in `DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id=1; INSERT INTO t1 (id) VALUES (2)`my `ON UPDATE` is invalid? Even if I had known about that behaviour I would have guessed that the `ON UPDATE` could be ignored.